# How to retain the value of combobox in struts 1 after wrong submisstion

Tags: jquery, combobox, struts-1

I am using a userForm to submit user attribute in struts 1 in the form i am using a combobox to submit values but my problem is that when i am submitting or refreshing the form (i.e if the page has some validation issues) the selected values in the userForm is disappeared   ..

```
<div class="row">
                <label for="lbl-01"><bean:message key="registrationForm.contactState"/> <span class="formElementRequired">*</span></label>

                 <span id='ajaxContent'>                                                                         
                                    <html:select property="stateAddressId" styleId="stateAddressId" styleClass="lookSelect" onchange="showCityForState(this.value);" >         
                                          <html:option value="0"><bean:message key="tml.registration.option.selectState"/></html:option> 

                                 <c:if test="${stateList!=null}">
                                    <logic:iterate id="stateObject" name="stateList">
                                     <html:option value="${stateObject.id}"><bean:write name="stateObject" property="description"/></html:option>
                                    </logic:iterate>
                                  </c:if>     

                                      </html:select> 
                            </span> 


                    <logic:messagesPresent property="stateAddressId">
                        <font color="red"><html:errors property="stateAddressId" /></font>
                </logic:messagesPresent>    

            </div>


            <div class="row">
                <label for="lbl-01"><bean:message key="registrationForm.contactCity"/> <span class="formElementRequired">*</span></label>

                 <span id='ajaxContentForCity'>                                                                         
                                    <html:select property="cityAddressId" styleId="cityAddressId" styleClass="lookSelect">         
                                          <html:option value="0"><bean:message key="tml.registration.option.selectCity"/></html:option> 


                                 <c:if test="${cityList!=null}">
                                    <logic:iterate id="cityObject" name="cityList">
                                     <html:option value="${cityObject.id}"><bean:write name="cityObject" property="description"/></html:option>
                                    </logic:iterate>
                                  </c:if> 

                                      </html:select> 
                            </span>


                    <logic:messagesPresent property="cityAddressId">
                        <font color="red"><html:errors property="cityAddressId" /></font>
                </logic:messagesPresent>    


            </div>
```

This is my action where i am setting the values

```
ReferenceService referenceService = (ReferenceService) GetSrvContxt.getInstance(request, "ReferenceService");
            Vector<CityObject> cityVector = new Vector<CityObject>();
            Vector<StateObject> stateVector = new Vector<StateObject>();
            stateVector = referenceService.getStateList(registrationObject
                    .getContactObject().getContactCity().getContactState()
                    .getContactCountry().getId());
            cityVector = referenceService.getCityDetails(registrationObject
                    .getContactObject().getContactCity().getContactState()
                    .getId());

            request.setAttribute("stateList", stateVector);
            request.setAttribute("cityList", cityVector);
```

Comment: That's some exciting indentation; please consider indenting consistently, and formatting for better SO legibility.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the values ​​between requests, you need to change the `scope` of the ActionForm instance to `session`. By default, it is in the `session`. But perhaps it is set to `request`, e.g.:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<struts-config>
   <form-beans>
      <form-bean name="CustomerForm" type="mybank.example.CustomerForm" />
   </form-beans>
   <action-mappings>
      <action path="/submitDetailForm" 
              type="mybank.example.CustomerAction" 
              name="CustomerForm" 
              scope="session" 
              validate="true" 
              input="/CustomerDetailForm.jsp">
         <forward name="success" path="/ThankYou.jsp" redirect="true" />
         <forward name="failure" path="/Failure.jsp" />
      </action>
   </action-mappings>
</struts-config>
```